# Redirect a subdomain url to a domain url with paramter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using htaccess mod-rewrite to redirect a subdomain url to a domain url with paramter, for example:

```
subdomain.example.com is redirect to example.com?id=subdomain
subdomain.example.com/page is redirect to example.com/page/?id=subdomain
subdomain.example.com/page1/page2 is redirect to example.com/page1/page2/?id=subdomain
subdomain.example.com/page1/page2?pol=abc is redirect to example.com/page1/page2/?id=subdomain&pol=abc
```

I use this code in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://example.com/$1?id=%1 [R,L]
```

Wildcards is enable for this domain.

This work good when url is subdomain.domain.com, but when in url are directories redirect dosn't work. For example when I write address subdomain.example.com/page in a web browser I get the same address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make it work with one rule.

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1?id=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1?id=%1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

You can test it with the [online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

Explanation:

1. line: Check if the query string is present.
2. line: Check if the request is directed to a subdomain.
3. line: Rewrite to a new address with the query build from the subdomain name and the original query string.
4. line: If the previous rewrite conditions and rule were not met, proceed with this one which is the same as the line 3. but without the query string presence checking.
5. line: Rewrite in the same manner but without adding the original query string.

`[R=302,L,NC]` stands for

- R=302 - Redirect with HTTP code 302 - temporary redirect so that browsers won't cache it while you test it
- L - Do not process further rules if this one was met
- NC - Perform the check in non case-sensitive manner